# JSON conversion for outer key value pair

Tags: javascript, python

I have one JSON in following structure:

```
data = {
    "a" : "1",
    "b" : {
        "c" : 2
    }
}
```

I want to convert it to following structure:

```
data = {
    a = "1",
    b = {
        "c":2
    }
}
```

I have tried to use map, but not getting correct way to do the conversion.

Comment: the expected structure is wrong

Comment: In Lex one function it is expecting this output format only@brk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
    const data = {
      a: "1",
      b: {
        c: 2
      }
    };
    
    const convertJson = data => {
      const _data = [];
      Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
        _data.push(`${key}=${JSON.stringify(data[key])}`);
      });
    
      return `{${_data.join(",")}}`;
    };
    
    console.log(convertJson(data));
```